# How do I set the table names for a Celery DB broker?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm using a shared postgres instance which hosts data from multiple groups, managing permissions via postgres schemas. Effectively, this means all of my tables need to be prefixed with my schema name like so:

```
my_schema.my_table
```

For the results backend of Celery, I found this [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-table-names) which mentions that `database_table_names` may be used to set the name of the tables used in the results backend.

Is it possible to use this setting to set the broker table names too?

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/56593ab2fd459dbb32c9dfaead3005bd3b4c59ee/celery/backends/database/__init__.py#L86), it doesn't appear to be possible. But, maybe there's another way to do this.